# Can you please explain what article is used in

Tags: grammar

Be careful of ___dog(a,an,the,no article)

Comment: We always use the ***definite article*** in such contexts. Note that idiomatically, in a *spoken* context we'd probably be more likely to warn someone ***Watch out for** the dog*, and for the *written* context it's almost always ***Beware of** the dog* (as a sign on a front gate, for example).

Comment: "Be careful of the dog" normally refers to a single, specific dog (e.g. if there is one dog in a yard/garden). If you're telling people to beware of all dogs, or to beware of more than one dog, you will need something else.

Comment: "Be careful of the dog" makes me think you need to not accidentally tread on its toes in this confined space, or catch his tail under your rocking chair, rather than be worried it might bite you. It's an odd way of putting it, if they mean 'beware'.